# How can I overload the assignment operation in Rust?

Tags: rust, assignment-operator

There are lots of operations in [`std::ops`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/index.html), but there is nothing for a simple assignment.

I'm coming from a C++ background, where there are copy constructor and assignment operator overloading that do the work for you. I need something like that in Rust.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You **cannot** overload assignment. Moving a variable from one location to another is a core component of Rust's ownership semantics and is not overridable.

Another answer suggests that you custom-implement the `Copy` trait. This makes no sense, as [*there's nothing to implement*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html):

```
pub trait Copy: Clone { }
```

You could implement [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) for a type, but to use `clone` you have to call it explicitly:

```
let foo = bar.clone();
```

The *actual assignment* is still just copying bits from the right-hand side to the left-hand side, the only difference is that you don't give up ownership of `bar`.

---

**If** your type can be duplicated by simply copying bits, then it's appropriate to implement `Copy`. **If** it can be duplicated by executing some kind of function, then it's appropriate to implement `Clone`. There is no way I know of to implicitly execute code at any given assignment of a type (and I count that as a **good thing**).

Comment: I realized, my understanding of Rust assignment was wrong, as I said in my question, I came in Rust with C++ back. (that most of the time makes confusion.)