# Method for safely moving all elements out of a generic array into a tuple with minimal overhead

Tags: arrays, rust, move

In Rust, I want to move all the elements out of a generic fixed-width array so I may then move them individually. The elements may but don't necessarily implement `Copy`. I've come up with the following solution:

```
struct Vec3<T> {
    underlying_array: [T; 3]
}

impl<T> Vec3<T> {
    fn into_tuple(self) -> (T, T, T) {
        let result = (
            unsafe { mem::transmute_copy(&self.underlying_array[0]) },
            unsafe { mem::transmute_copy(&self.underlying_array[1]) },
            unsafe { mem::transmute_copy(&self.underlying_array[2]) },
        );
        mem::forget(self);
        result
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but I want to know if it's safe in the general case. Coming from C++, it's not generally safe to move objects by copying their bit patterns and bypassing the source object's destructor, which I think is essentially what I'm doing here. But in Rust, every type is movable (I think) and there's no way to customize move semantics (I think), so I can't think of any other way Rust would implement moving objects in the un-optimized case than a bitwise copy.

Is moving elements out of an array like this safe? Is there a more idiomatic way to do it? Is the Rust compiler smart enough to elide the actual bit copying `transmute_copy` does when possible, and if not, is there a faster way to do this?

I think this is **not** a duplicate of [How do I move values out of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406251/how-do-i-move-values-out-of-an-array) because in that example, the array elements aren't generic and don't implement `Drop`. The library in the accepted answer moves individual values out of the array one at a time while keeping the rest of the array usable. Since I want to move all the values at once and don't care about keeping the array, I think this case is different.

Comment: Did you have a chance to read the answers to the question, which *do* address the concerns of `Drop`? On Stack Overflow, a duplicate doesn't mean that the question was identical, but that *the same answers apply*. For example, I could copy and paste the accepted answer here and it would seemingly fit perfectly to answer the question in your title. You have a lot of *other* questions in the body that are ancillary to the question in the title, though.

Comment: It addresses `Drop` by saying the the first part of the answer doesn't handle it and then references a library that does. But I looked at the library and it moves individual values out of the array one at a time while keeping the rest of the array usable. Since I want to move all the values at once and don't care about keeping the array, I think this case is different.

Comment: As for the difference between using `replace` + `unitialized` vs `transmute_copy`, I could make that a separate question if you'd like, but I don't think the rest of the questions are ancillary since i'm asking for the minimal overhead way of doing this that's also safe in the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Rust 1.36 and up

This can now be done in completely safe code:

```
impl<T> Vec3<T> {
    fn into_tuple(self) -> (T, T, T) {
        let [a, b, c] = self.underlying_array;
        (a, b, c)
    }
}
```

## Previous versions

As you've mentioned and as discussed in [How do I move values out of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34406251/155423), treating a generic type as a bag of bits can be very dangerous. Once we have copied those bits and they are "live", implementations of traits such as `Drop` can access the value when we least expect it.

That being said, your current code *appears* to be safe, but has needless flexibility. Using `transmute` or `transmute_copy` is The Big Hammer and is actually rarely needed. You don't want the ability to change the type of the value. Instead, use [`ptr::read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.read.html).

It's conventional to expand `unsafe` blocks to cover the range of code that makes something safe and then to include a comment explaining *why* the block is actually safe. In this case, I'd expand it to cover the `mem::forget`; the returned expression has to come along for the ride too.

You will need to ensure that it's **impossible** for a panic to occur between the time that you've moved the first value out and when you forget the array. Otherwise your array *will* be half-initialized and you *will* trigger uninitialized behavior. In this case, I like your structure of writing a single statement that creates the resulting tuple; it's harder to accidentally shoehorn in extra code in there. This is also worth adding comments for.

```
use std::{mem, ptr};

struct Vec3<T> {
    underlying_array: [T; 3],
}

impl<T> Vec3<T> {
    fn into_tuple(self) -> (T, T, T) {
        // This is not safe because I copied it directly from Stack Overflow
        // without reading the prose associated with it that said I should 
        // write my own rationale for why this is safe.
        unsafe {
            let result = (
                ptr::read(&self.underlying_array[0]),
                ptr::read(&self.underlying_array[1]),
                ptr::read(&self.underlying_array[2]),
            );
            mem::forget(self);
            result
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

> every type is movable

Yes, I believe this to be correct. You can [make certain values immovable though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32300133/155423) (search for "one specific case".

> there's no way to customize move semantics

Yes, [I believe this to be correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37377250/155423).

> Is the Rust compiler smart enough to elide the actual bit copying

In general, I would trust the compiler to do so, yes. However, optimization is a tricky thing. Ultimately, only looking at assembly and profiling in your real case will tell you the truth.

> is there a faster way to do this?

Not that I'm aware of.

---

I'd normally write such code as:

```
extern crate arrayvec;
extern crate itertools;

use arrayvec::ArrayVec;
use itertools::Itertools;

struct Vec3<T> {
    underlying_array: [T; 3],
}

impl<T> Vec3<T> {
    fn into_tuple(self) -> (T, T, T) {
        ArrayVec::from(self.underlying_array).into_iter().next_tuple().unwrap()
    }
}
```

Investigating the assembly for both implementations, the first one takes 25 x86_64 instructions and the second takes 69. Again, I'd rely on profiling to know which was *actually* faster, since more instructions doesn't necessarily mean slower.

See also:

- [How do I move values out of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34406251/155423)
- [How do I move String values from an array to a tuple without copying?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38290790/155423)

Comment: I'd also note that the documentation for `ptr::read` states that it "semantically moves the value out of `src`..." which helps with my concern that a bitwise copy might not always be equivalent to a move.

Comment: In this case it's quite clear that panics won't happen in the critical parts of the code. In cases where I'm less certain, I prefer using `std::mem::ManuallyDrop` over `mem::forget`, since it means that a panic will only leak memory and not cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm not sure if I understood correctly. In you first code snippet is the mem::forget(self) always necessary in this situation?

Comment: @Ph.Weier make sure you see my update on the better way to write this now. Yes, the `mem::forget` is necessary, otherwise you can end up with two owners of the data inside the array. If `T` is a `String`, that would lead to an attempt to free the string multiple times, causing memory unsafety.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Oh that looks very nice with the new version. What if we need to move an arbitrarly sized array, is then the `ptr::read` way still the way to go? I heard of `std::array::IntoIter::new(array)` to get a consuming iterator but this appears to still be a non stable feature.

Comment: @Ph.Weier you [can't have an "arbitrarily sized array"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28136739/155423), so I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yeah that was not a very precise question indead. I'm refering to the GenericArray from the crate [Inline Link](https://docs.rs/generic-array/0.14.1/generic_array/). In which case I cannot work use something like `let [a,b,c,d] = generic_array` as the size will only be known at compilation. To circumvent this I'm using the `std::ptr::read(&generic_array[i])` approach to get ownership. Note that I always go through the whole array to construct a new one. Maybe this has not it's place in comments and I should just open a new thread for my specific issue.

Comment: @Ph.Weier that crate appears to have a [by-value iterator](https://docs.rs/generic-array/0.14.1/generic_array/iter/struct.GenericArrayIter.html#impl-Iterator). Applied to an [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a37934f9e7759fbd5574908c053857ce).

Comment: Thank you very much that was it! I somehow tried that at some point but had a problem using a Deref trait implementation on the newtype on the GenericArray. After accessing the inner data directly without using any deref it works as expected :)